# Unable to connect Cassandra CQL shell to Azure-CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-cassandra-api

I have entered the following command on my windows cql shell

`set SSL_VERSION=TLSv1_2;`

and got this error

`No viable alternative at input 'set'([set]..)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this error when you atemmpt to set the variable or upon launching the cqlsh cmd?

Please ensure you have the two following variables set, where SSL_CERTFILE references a trusted root ca bundle. This is the trusted root bundle from an OpenSSL install on Ubuntu.

export **SSL_VERSION**=TLSv1_2
export **SSL_CERTFILE**=/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Optionally, you can use: export **SSL_VALIDATE**=true should there be any concerns with the certificate.

In windows, you use `set` instead of `export`.

Answer (score 0):

Use export in place of set. Export is used for Linux and Serbia used for windows